# Is Aura Page to LWC the only way to call LWC from Case button?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I am trying to create a button on Case and have it navigate to a LWC that contains a custom table.

I found that on Case you have to make it a dynamic action. I also found that you can not call from one LWC to another. When doing this I get error `This page isn't available in Salesforce Lightning Experience or mobile app`. After some research it looks like the best way to do this is to call the LWC from an aura component.

This feels redundant using Aura and LWC from a button so I was curious if anyone has any other suggestions on calling a LWC from a button on Case?

when I click on view all test v4 the table below it drops down. I want this table to open in a new window
[image]

Comment: No LWC can be directly called, they need a container. Are you setting your LWC up as a quick action?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely make a LWC available as a quick action.

[image]

Go here:
[yourorgurl]/lightning/setup/ObjectManager/Case/ButtonsLinksActions/newAction

Make sure your component meta xml file looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
  <isExposed>true</isExposed>
  <masterLabel>Your Quick Action Name</masterLabel>
  <description>What your quick action does</description>
  <targets>
      <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
      <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
  </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

In your lwc js file, to get access to the `recordId` you just need this line:

```
@api recordId;
```

Unfortunately, sometimes it's not available immediately to the lwc, so you can either use it in a wiredmethod using the `$recordId` syntax (which fires the wire method when the value changes)

Or you can make a setter for `recordId` and call your init from that. It's bad practice I know, because of single responsibility etc... But it works.

Or finally, you could set a timer to check if recordId has changed and init on that.

Here's the setter:

```
_recordId;
@api
set recordId(value) {
  this._recordId = value;
  this.init();
}
get recordId() {
  return this._recordId;
}
```

Comment: thank you for this. I am able to create a LWC quick action button but when I do this the page pops INSIDE of the button. Do you know if there is a way to pop it into a new page outside of the button? I update the post to show the LWC inside button